# Complexity Analysis: Remove consecutive(3+) duplicates from string

Tags: string, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have written a solution for removing 3(let's call this k) or more consecutive same characters from string. 
eg.

```
in: daabbcccbbaad out: dd
in: aaabbb out: 
in: aaabbbc out: c
```

code:

```
void removeDup(string& s, int start) {
    if (s.length() < 3) {
        return;
    }

    if (start > s.length() - 2) return;

    int count = 1;
    char c = s[start];

    int i = start + 1;

    while (i < s.length() && s[i] == c) {
        ++count, ++i;
    }

    if (count >= 3) {
        start = i - count - 2;
        if (start < 0) start = 0;
        s.erase(i - count, count);
    } else {
        start = i;
    }

    return removeDup(s, start);
}
```

For each match `start` pointer will move 2 step behind. Also problem size is reducing by no of matched characters.

I want to understand how to do complexity analysis for this. Also for any `k`(let's say `k=n/2`) how will the complexity change.

ps: if you have a better solution with constant space, kindly post.

Comment: @nissimabehcera I guess worst case will be when one has to iterate again on previously parsed input. let say something like `aabcccbba`. This can go in worst case where all characters are removed starting from `n/2...ccc...n/2`, in such case previous n/2 ip will be parsed again and again until all are removed. Not sure how will complexity look like in this case.

Comment: Sorry, i'm mistaken about while loop and a line :    if (count >= 3) 
At Best : it's a least expansive way to an algorithm to solve a problem.
At worst : it's the contrary.
it's most expansive way

At best : length of string = 3 and constituted of 3 duplicates.After erase method call , length of string is equal to 0.Then ' remove up ' is called recursively and return void (s.length=0) immediately
At worst (need to verify)    if string looks like   abcdefghijjjj
8 recursive calls "for nothing" , then 4 duplicates against 4 recursive calls for aabcccbba

Comment: You can count each elementary operations like additions , comparisons etc... to determine if aabcccbba is more or not expansive than abcdefghijjjj